# build VDProj without Visual Studio installed

Tags: c#, .net

We are using Visual Studio 2008 and .Net 3.5. we can build our C# projects in build machine by using MSBuild from SDK because we don't have visual studio installed on the build machine.

Now we are trying to build the Setup project with similar settings. It looks like the MSBuild doesn't like .vDProj. any idea how can we do that?

thanks,

EDIT:

the build machine only has SDK installed, no Visual Studio installed, no other thirdparty build tool installed.

Comment: Ugh, crummy question.  What does "doesn't like" mean?  Does it work on your dev machine?

Comment: You think the question is invalid? I am looking for a way to build vdproj without Visual Studio installed. not clear? I am looking for a way to build vdproj on a machine which doesn't have Visual Studio installed. I knew Microsoft SDK cannot do it but some experts here may have workaround. That is why I am asking here. "doesn't like" here means MSBuild cannot build it, cannot recognize it as a valid parameter. I don't know what's wrong with it. My dev machine must has Visual Studio installed so no problem to build it.

Comment: Have you tried converting the project to '.NET 4'/VS2010 format and then use MSBuild to build it? I dont think being .NET 4 would make a difference with native code. PS: I agree, valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Visual Studio on the Build machine.